# Filter Map<String,Object> by outer key and also using inner key using a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I want to filter a `Map<String,Object>` using the outer and inner key values.

My map:

```java
Map<String,Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("account",account);
dataMap.put("productDetails",listOfProductDetails);
```

```json
{
  "account": "JV-013",
  "productDetails": [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productName": "birew",
      "productVersion": [
        "v1.0",
        "v2.0"
      ],
      "productOwner": [
        {
          "ownerName": "John",
          "ownerMail": "john34@yahoo.com"
        },
        {
          "ownerName": "Pav",
          "ownerMail": "pavghig@yahoo.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productName": "rowa",
      "productVersion": [
        "v1.0",
        "v2.0"
      ],
      "productOwner": [
        {
          "ownerName": "John",
          "ownerMail": "john34@yahoo.com"
        },
        {
          "ownerName": "Rias",
          "ownerMail": "rias765@yahoo.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter "account" which is outer key, and "productName","ownerName" which are the inner keys for the list of items in the Map, as below,

```json
{
  "account": "JV-013",
  "productDetails": [
    {
      "productName": "birew",
      "productOwner": [
        {
          "ownerName": "John"
        },
        {
          "ownerName": "Pav"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productName": "rowa",
      "productOwner": [
        {
          "ownerName": "John"
        },
        {
          "ownerName": "Rias"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The filtering keys are not fixed; time to time it can change.

I tried the below,

```java
public Map<String, Object> filterUsingMap(String filterKeys) throws IOException {
       Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
     dataMap.put("account",account);
       dataMap.put("productDetails",listOfProductDetails);

    filterKeys = account,productDetails.productName,productDetails.productOwner.ownerName
//nestedkeys are using Dot to differentiate

       List<String> str = Arrays.asList(filterKeys .split(","));

       //filter map with fields
        Map<String, Object> filteredMap1 = dataMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> str.contains(entry.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));


        return filteredMap1;

    }
```

This only filters the outer keys, can someone help to filter the nestedKeys also?

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output